# Reshape dataset in R_ move row to column

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I have a dataset with the below format:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e17f5.png)

```
structure(list(SNPID = c("SNP_A-1780520", "SNP_A-1780618", "SNP_A-1780632"
), no.1 = c("BB", "AB", "AA"), no.2 = c("BB", "AB", "AA"), no.3 = c("BB", 
"AB", "AB")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))`
```

I want to reshape the dataset to have each SNPID as a column and each "no" as a row.

I have tried different R packages but I was not successful to manage this simple task. I appreciate any help. I would like to have someting like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj5km.png)

Comment: Hi Milad. Please provide some reproducible data (e.g. with the function `dput()`). Thanks

Comment: Something like this using (`library(tidyr)`)? `df %>% pivot_longer(-SNPID) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = SNPID, values_from = value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example on reshaping your data with [tidyr()](https://uc-r.github.io/tidyr)

```
library (tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-SNPID) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = SNPID, values_from = value)

   name  `SNP_A-1780520` `SNP_A-1780618` `SNP_A-1780632` `SNP_A-1780654`
  <chr> <chr>           <chr>           <chr>           <chr>          
1 no.1  BB              AB              AA              AA             
2 no.2  BB              AB              AA              AA             
3 no.3  BB              AB              AA              AA
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R and as oneliner:

```
df = structure(list(SNPID = c("SNP_A-1780520", "SNP_A-1780618", "SNP_A-1780632" ), no.1 = c("BB", "AB", "AA"), no.2 = c("BB", "AB", "AA"), no.3 = c("BB",  "AB", "AB")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",  "data.frame"))

df_new = as.data.frame(t(df))
```

**Output:**

```
df_new
                 V1            V2            V3
SNPID SNP_A-1780520 SNP_A-1780618 SNP_A-1780632
no.1             BB            AB            AA
no.2             BB            AB            AA
no.3             BB            AB            AB
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be a case for `data.table::transpose`

```
data.table::transpose(df1, make.names = "SNPID",  keep.names = "name")
  name SNP_A-1780520 SNP_A-1780618 SNP_A-1780632
1 no.1            BB            AB            AA
2 no.2            BB            AB            AA
3 no.3            BB            AB            AB
```